Skin modifier doesn't add any verticies
I am trying to follow this tutorial on how to model a dragon (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TR8nYG0DtJc&ab_channel=RicSanCustomToys) (I know its old and that theres probably better ones but I couldnt find any good and I need a tutorial since I am new to blender). He removes 3 of the vertices from the plane and then get new ones once he adds the skin modifier, but I dont. I dont get any new vertices and I do not understand why.

What is the exact timestamp when this happens? The video is three quarters of an hour long, which is too much to just search through for what you’re describing.

The Skin modifier showed vertices in older versions, but not anymore. It doesn't matter anyway, because these vertices are just virtual vertices created by the modifier, they are not selectable or editable or anything. The only vertex he is working with is the one in the center which he keeps extruding and moving to create more.

So it doesnt matter that I cant see the verticles? Thanks for the help
